# Can a subset of a sphere with countably many points on each great circle have nonzero measure?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

A set $A$ of points on $S^2$, the two-dimensional sphere, has the following property:

$$\forall c(\theta,\phi) \mbox{, the set } (A\cap c(\theta,\phi)) \mbox{ is countable.}$$

Where $c(\theta, \phi)$ is the great circle described by two angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ in the conventional sense.

Can $A$ be a set of nonzero Lebesgue measure over the whole sphere?

The statement doesn't seem trivially true to me since the sphere can't be expressed as a countable union of great circles.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for the suggestion Noah- is there a way to easily see that the formulation you give is equivalent despite the different topology of vertical lines in [0,1]x[0,1] compared to great circles on a 2-sphere? Note also that Vitali sets are uncountable so I don't think provide a counterexample here.

Comment: Hm, it's not quite as easy as I thought - if you replace "great circle" with "line of longitude" then it works, but that's different. Bah. I'll leave my comment up though in case it's helpful to someone.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Wow, that was very full of wrong. Comment deleted! However, I do think my idea for a negative solution in the measurable case may be good. Repeating it with more clarity: suppose $A$ is a subset of the sphere with the above properties. Pick a large enough "square shaped" region $S$ of the sphere in which $A$ has positive measure, and now biject that appropriately with the unit square, and let $B$ be the image of $A\cap S$ under that bijection. Now $B$ has the property that every vertical line intersects $B$ only countably many times (by picking our map reasonably well) (cont'd)

Comment: and again by picking our map reasonably well, the image of $B$ has positive measure. And this should give a contradiction to Fubini's theorem. So I think even if we replace "great circle" with "line of longitude," the answer is no *in the measurable case*.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, it seems clear that if $A$ is measurable then the result follows from Fubini, one way or another. My thought was there should be an argument having something to do with Haar measure on the orthogonal group - no, I don't see exactly how that goes.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oooh, that'd be slicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no in the measurable case.

Suppose $A\subseteq S^2$ has positive measure but intersects every *circle of longitude* countably often (so in fact we're  proving a stronger result). We can find a "square-shaped" region $R$ on $S^2$ - that is, given by connecting four "corners" with lines of latitude and longitude respectively - such that $A\cap R$ has positive measure.

Now it's not hard to construct a bijection $b$ between $R$ and $[0, 1]^2$ such that the preimage of any null set is null and which maps lines of longitude to vertical lines. We have that $b(A)$ is a subset of $[0, 1]^2$ of positive measure which intersects every vertical line at most countably many times.

Now apply Fubini's theorem. We get that the measure of $b(A)$ is $\int\int_A1d\mu=\int_{[0, 1]} 0dx=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: I believe that one. Except if you reread the question you see you're showing the answer is _yes_, not _no_. Picky picky...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Except if you read the title question ... :P

Comment: Touche. We need a new  policy - if the question is stated twice it should be in a way such that both one-word answers are the same.

Comment: Edited for consistency